# Open Putty through Keepass

Tags: putty, cmd.exe, keepass

Keepass has a way to open programs and autotype/login. But I can't get putty to work.
I installed putty (and it's other programs) with the installer.

But no mater what I put in the `cmd` or `win+R` Putty won't start

Putty is installed on the D drive But firefox is also installed on the D drive and that works.

How do I fix this?

[image: Url Overrides]

Comment: Is Putty in your path? You can check this by win + R and then typing "putty.exe" and pressing enter. This should open Putty. If it doesn't, you need to add it to your path asper here: http://zeth.net/archive/2006/05/26/putty-series-adding-putty-to-your-system-path/

Comment: Putty appearently is not im the path. I'll check it out later. Is this still the way to go in Win8.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the built-in override and add a custom one with `cmd://d:/path/to/putty.exe -ssh {USERNAME}:{BASE:RMVSCM}`.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this URL works "\\Host.domain.tld\c$\windows\tools\putty.exe -load PuttyProfile".
But because of a $ Share Adminrights are necessary.

Comment: Put putty on your local system, and then either add Putty to your path or make your URL a local path. Also don't add stuff manually to your windows folder. If you don't want to use Putty's installer, do something like c:\tools\putty\putty.exe.